# How to use a proxy for a link with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm working on a website using Reactjs and Typescript for the front-end and the backend is in Java. While I'm developing I use port 3000 for the frontend and the 8080 for the backend. I have setup the proxy property on the **package.json**

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

so I don't have any problem while I'm doing requests to the backend because the proxy works perfectly.

Now I need to create some links to download reports, so I'm generating dynamically the links and I need them to point to the port **8080** and not to the port **3000**

I'm passing the url like:

```
<a href={this.state.url}>Download Report</a>
```

where *this.state.url* looks like **/reports/download/users** and make sense its pointing to **http://3000/reports/download/users**

Any idea how to create the links in dev to point to the port 8080.

**Updated**

The proxy is working with a request like the below code:

```
   fetch('./app/admin/reports/availableReports')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => json.reportTypes)
    .catch(ex => {
        console.log('Alert!!', ex)
        return []
    })
```

But its not working when I generate a url link:

```
<a href={'app' + this.state.currentDownloadUrl}>Download Report</a>
```

Comment: Isn't that what the proxy is doing? You request `http://localhost:3000/reports/download/users` and the proxy points that to `:8080` instead. The advantage of using a proxy is that you can use *relative* routes for everything even though the front end and back end are running on separate ports in dev.

Comment: yep, but its not working on the links, just when I request something by a fetch but while I use url links always point to port 3000 (I mean to the front-end) @jonrsharpe

Comment: And is the proxy *not* working when you click on them?

Comment: Nop. The proxy just work when ajax requests but in case of a link is always pointing to the front-end port. I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I used one not a very good solution I think, but it works for me.

```
<a href={`http://localhost:8000${record_detail_item.file}`} download>Download File</a>
```

You can have some global variable which points to your dev server and you can use it instead of `http://localhost:8000`

- **Update:**
  Instead of hardcoding URL, you can set up environment variables [Create-react-app environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `proxy` property to set the backend base url. [As per the doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/):

> Keep in mind that `proxy` only has effect in development (with `npm start`), and it is up to you to ensure that URLs like `/api/todos` point to the right thing in production.

When you build your app, it won't work.

You should [add an environment variable](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) for your backend base URL and prepend it when you make backend calls.

Something like

```
   fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/app/admin/reports/availableReports`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => json.reportTypes)
    .catch(ex => {
        console.log('Alert!!', ex)
        return []
    })
```

```
<a href={`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}${this.state.currentDownloadUrl}`}>Download Report</a>
```